# R - Subtitle not showing everything

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My plot is not showing the max function after the string (image of plot attached). I've tried to add more strings after commas and they don't appear either. I'm still pretty new to R, an explanation would be appreciated. Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLAdE.png)

```
combined_data_chart <- ggplot(data = combined_data, aes(x= '', y=  sum_all_pips, fill Text_dates)) +
      geom_bar(stat='identity') +
      geom_text(aes(label =floor(sum_all_pips)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+ 
      theme_classic() + 
      coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
      theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
      theme(axis.line = element_blank()) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
      labs(title = 'Pip Count per month from 2011-2020') +
      labs(subtitle = 'Max :', max(combined_data$sum_all_pips)
```

Comment: You tell `labs()` `subtitle = 'Max :'` and then it has no idea what you want to do with the next argument, `max(combined_data$sum_all_pips)`. Paste together the subtitle string so you're giving a single object to `subtitle =`. Like this: `labs(subtitle = paste('Max:', max(combined_data$sum_all_pips)))`. And make sure you get all the `)`.